# Does below Dynamodb scenario valid?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Can we get exceptions because of network failures While writing the data to dynamodb post data written to the tables ?

Comment: Are you asking if there can be network errors *after* the data is written, but *before* the client receives a response? Yes, I would assume that's possible.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This can happen:

- You post the data to dynamo successfully
- Dynamo successfully writes the data
- Dynamo servers return a 200 OK
- A network error causes the TCP connection to time out or fail in some other way before the data makes it back from the dynamo servers to your client

In this case, the data exists happily on the server, but your code was never notified about it.

See the Two Generals' Problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem